# Trying to migrate a WordPress site AWAY from AWS Lightsail, can't install a simple plugin

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, migration

The admin of the site has no clue and can't seem to get me credentials on how to install a migration plugin without asking for FTP creds, which they don't know how to provide.

Any ideas? They gave me "root" login access but the structure is 100% new to me.

I tried logging in and snooping around with no luck, all the tutorials have interfaces that look much different.

Comment: You might receive a better response at: https://serverfault.com or https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/